# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.id' in 'where clause' sonata symfony

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony-forms, sonata-admin

I have two entity, Entity `Devisvente` extend entity `Ventes` in sonata admin bundle ,

This is my entity `Ventes` :

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Ventes
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ventes")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VentesRepository")
 */
class Ventes
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="reference", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $reference;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime")
 */
private $date;


#...........


 #...........
}
```

and this is my entity `Devisvente` extend Ventes table:

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Devisvente
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ventes")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VentesRepository")
 */

class Devisvente extends Ventes {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

}
```

Each class has a admin class (ex : entity Ventes has a VentesAdmin.php)
this is my class admin to entity `Ventes` :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

class VentesAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper

    ->with('Facture', array('class' => 'col-md-6'))
    ->add('compte', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\compte',
                'choice_label' => 'raison_sociale',
                'required' => false
                ))
    ->add('objet', 'text')
    ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'  => array(
                    'Facture' => 'Facture partie ventes',

                )))
    ->add('reference', 'text')
    ->add('date', 'sonata_type_date_picker')
    ->end()
    ->with('Autres Informations', array('class' => 'col-md-6'))
    ->add('User', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
            'choice_label' => 'username',
            'required' => false
            ))
    ->add('commission', 'text')
    ->add('validite_du_devis', 'number')
    ->add('mode_de_paiement', 'text')
    ->add('compte_bancaire', 'text')
    ->end()
    ->with('Acticles', array('class' => 'col-md-12'))
    ->add('articles', 'sonata_type_model', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Article',
        'property' => 'reference',
        'multiple' => true
    ))
    ->end()
    ->with('Packs', array('class' => 'col-md-12'))
    ->add('packs', 'sonata_type_model', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\packs',
        'property' => 'reference',
        'multiple' => true
    ))
    ->end()
    ;
}
#......
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
    ->addIdentifier('reference')
    ->add('compte.raison_sociale')
    ->add('date')
    ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
        'actions' => array(
            'show' => array(),
            'edit' => array(),
            'delete' => array(),
        )))
    ;
}
}
```

and this is my class admin to entity `Devisvente` :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;


class DevisventeAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
#......
#......
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper

    ->with('Facture', array('class' => 'col-md-6'))
    ->add('compte', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\compte',
                'choice_label' => 'raison_sociale',
                'required' => false
                ))
    ->add('objet', 'text')
    ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'choices'  => array(
                    'Facture' => 'Facture partie ventes',

                )))
    ->add('reference', 'text')
    ->add('date', 'sonata_type_date_picker')
    ->end()
    ->with('Autres Informations', array('class' => 'col-md-6'))
    ->add('User', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
            'choice_label' => 'username',
            'required' => false
            ))
    ->add('commission', 'text')
    ->add('validite_du_devis', 'number')
    ->add('mode_de_paiement', 'text')
    ->add('compte_bancaire', 'text')
    ->end()
    ->with('Acticles', array('class' => 'col-md-12'))
    ->add('articles', 'sonata_type_model', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Article',
        'property' => 'reference',
        'multiple' => true
    ))
    ->end()
    ->with('Packs', array('class' => 'col-md-12'))
    ->add('packs', 'sonata_type_model', array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\packs',
        'property' => 'reference',
        'multiple' => true
    ))
    ->end()
    ;
}
#......
#......
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
    ->addIdentifier('reference')
    ->add('compte.raison_sociale')
    ->add('date')
    ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
        'actions' => array(
            'show' => array(),
            'edit' => array(),
            'delete' => array(),
        )))
    ;
}
}
```

and when i want to show or edit or delete item from listField in Devisventes list:

[image]

As a result, I have this problem:

[image]

can you help me ????
This is my `services.yml`

```
    # Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
    #parameter_name: value

services:
    #service_name:
    #    class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
    #    arguments: ['@another_service_name', 'plain_value', '%parameter_name%']
    admin.facture:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\VentesAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Ventes, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Ventes, label: Facture, icon: "<i class=\"fa fa-file-text\"></i>" }
    admin.devisvente:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\DevisventeAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Devisvente, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Ventes, label: Devis }
    admin.user:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\UserAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\User, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Settings, label: Users, icon: "<i class=\"fa fa-cog\"></i>" }
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: could you show your entry in `services.yml` of the SonataAdmin service? The sql generated by SonataAdmin is wrong, so I suspect there is a malconfiguration there

Comment: admin.facture:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\VentesAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Ventes, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Ventes, label: Facture, icon: "<i class=\"fa fa-file-text\"></i>" }
    admin.devisvente:
        class: AppBundle\Admin\DevisventeAdmin
        arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Devisvente, ~]
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: Ventes, label: Devis }

Comment: this is my services.yml

Comment: You may want to edit your question to include the services.yml, instead in the comments. Its easier to read this way.  
You services look fine to me. Please do post you `configureFormFields` of the `VentesAdmin` (also please edit the question for this one)

Comment: okk wait please

Comment: i update my question and i add services.yml

Comment: i add configureFormFields in question

Comment: I would like to help you but unfortunately I never used Sonata in my projects. While you wait an answer (_during the week-end there are much less users here :-)_) you should check again and again your code step by step to be sure to have properly followed the directives contained in the Sonata docs. Maybe you will find the error by yourself 
 ;-) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the `$id` in the `DevisVente` Entity.

Comment: i remove $id in the deviseVente entity but same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related with the annotations.

Annotations for Parent class and child class points same table. I think you must to delete annotations in parent class if it is not mapped to database

```
/**
 * Ventes
 *
 * 
 * 
 */
class Ventes
{
  ...
}
```

Also properties should be declared as protected and not as private for inheriting

```
/**
 * Ventes
 *
 * 
 */
class Ventes
{
...
protected $id;
...
protected $reference;
...
protected $date;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. And to solve the problem I used doctrine inheritance mapping annotation:
[see Inheritance Mapping](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping)

Thus, you could store the data in a single table or set up class table inheritance.

Also, there is no need to override the `id` property in the derived class.
And as an alternative solution it is possible to create abstract parent class with the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation, so it is possible to store the data in separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else bumps into the same problem, I got the same error but it was due to a lowercase entity name in my doctrine xml model.

So instead of  `<entity name="Doctrine\Tests\ORM\Mapping\user" table="cms_users">` I had to capitalize the Entity:  `<entity name="Doctrine\Tests\ORM\Mapping\User" table="cms_users">`

It shows it here in the docs: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/xml-mapping.html#example

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).